# Deriving eigen values of $\hat{N}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, harmonic-oscillator, commutator, eigenvalue

So let's say we have an operator $\hat{a}$ (ladder operator), where $\left[\hat{a},\hat{a}^\dagger\right] = 1$, and $\hat{a}^2 |\phi\rangle = 0$.

How do I show that the eigenvalues of $\hat{N}=\hat{a}^\dagger \hat{a} $ are either zero or one. I suspect it has something to do with showing $\hat{N}^2=\hat{N}$, but I cannot figure out a way to do this.

Comment: is $[a,a^\dagger]=aa^\dagger\color{red}-a^\dagger a$ or $[a,a^\dagger]=aa^\dagger\color{red}+a^\dagger a$?

Comment: it is $aa^\dagger - a^\dagger a$

Comment: in that case, $\hat N$ is the usual (bosonic) number operator of a harmonic oscillator, right? (which means that its eigenvalues are $0,1,2,3,\cdots$, and not just $0,1$)

Comment: so if it was $+$ instead of $-$ would the eigenvalues the only be zero or one?

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to prove something false: the eigenvalues or $\hat N$ are **not** either zero or one. Any natural number is an eigenvalue of $\hat N$... (I believe your ladder operators are fermionic, that is, $[a,a^\dagger]=aa^\dagger\color{red}+a^\dagger a$)

Comment: lol this is interesting, does the fact that $\hat{a}^2 |\phi> = 0 $ affect this at all?

Comment: Not really: $a^2|\emptyset\rangle\Leftrightarrow a|\emptyset\rangle$, that is, you have a standard harmonic oscillator.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will attempt to solve this using the fermionic ladder operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much deliberation, I think I have found the answer:

$$ \hat{a }^\dagger \hat{a} = \hat{N} = \hat{a }^\dagger[\hat{a},\hat{a }^\dagger]\hat{a}$$
$$ = \hat{a }^\dagger(\hat{a} \hat{a }^\dagger - \hat{a }^\dagger\hat{a})\hat{a}$$

as $\hat{a}^2 = 0$, we have:

$$ \hat{a }^\dagger \hat{a} = \hat{N} = \hat{a }^\dagger \hat{a}\hat{a }^\dagger \hat{a} = \hat{N}^2$$

Therefore $\hat{N} = 0, 1$.